# iOS 5 split view modal view controller popup: possible or no dice?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, segue

I basically have a splitview controller and immediately I would like to show a popup modal view controller.

I have wired up the `UISplitView` class with a modal segue to my other view controller (LoginView, just a straight `UIViewController` subclass) I basically just want to show that on load and I'm pretty sure I shouldn't do this in the app delegate (however I could be wrong)

I want to do it with a

```
[something performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:something];
```

Where should I put it and what should I connect the segue to (I swear I have tried every different combination haha!)

(I'm using the universal master-detail view starting project from Xcode 4.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would display this from your initial detail view controller (the right pane of your split view) since it will always be sent a `-viewDidAppear:` message regardless of launch orientation.

In your `-viewDidAppear:` method, have the split view controller present the modal controller. Each view controller in a split view controller will already have its `splitViewController` property set. Ensure that your segue is connected from the split view controller (not one of its child view controllers) to the login view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.splitViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self.splitViewController];
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely amazing - why does this work (and what's the difference between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear?)

Comment: This works because the `-viewDidAppear:` message is automatically sent to your view controller when it's view appears on screen. `-viewDidLoad:` is sent once the view controller's view has been loaded and had all of its outlets connected.

Comment: Just another point - I put this in viewDidLoad and I alleviated the issues with the view underneath flashing up for a second before the modal view controller was displayed. still; thank you so so much!

Comment: I generally like to do my modal transitions in `-viewDidAppear:` so that the user has the benefit of seeing the view animate on to the screen. It helps them understand that this is a task that must be completed before operation with the app can continue. Apple uses this technique everywhere. Try launching `Messages.app` without any conversations and you'll see a blank table view before the new message modal is presented.

Comment: ahh yes, I see - every other animation I have is in view did appear, for that very reason - I just needed this animation on view did load so that the app looks like it's 'locked' (i.e. you can't 'get into' the main part of the app until you log in) but yeah, the main issue with mine was that I was trying to display a modal from the master view not the detail (probably before the split view had finished loading?)

Comment: If you launched in portrait, the master view controller wouldn't even be displayed on screen until the user taps the bar button.

Comment: touche - it makes so much sense now! :)

Comment: hey @MarkAdams I'm having problems with this atm. So I dont really understand where to connect my login is it like this? UISplitViewController -> (as modal) LoignView and then the UISplitViewController -> (for detailView) MainPageView. So two segues, one towards my main page and then the other one connected to the login? and then I call the viewdidappear on the MainPageView's class? Wasn't sure as it's throwing me an error that it couldn't find the segue which kinda make sense since it's not connected to that controller.